# bootstrap filtering values in "input=text" fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4

I have data to filter using bootstrap/jquery

i am not using table, just div row and cols

[my form looks like this example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LcgEG.jpg)

my code looks like this

```html
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4">
<input class="form-control form-control-sm" type="text" name="inspectiondetailLibelle_370329" value="Mécanosoudures"></div>
</div
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
  <input class="form-control form-control-sm" type="text" name="inspectiondetailLibelle_370330" value="Boulonneride"></div>
</div
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4">
<input class="form-control form-control-sm" type="text" name="inspectiondetailLibelle_370332" value="Bâti de flèche" ></div>
</div>
```

i want to filter values in input="text" fields (Mécanosoudures, Boulonneride, Bâti de flèche)

I tried this approach by puting the javascript

```html
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#MyInspectionModules").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $("#MyInspection *").filter(function() {
      $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
    });
  });
});
</script>
```

and then adding the search box

```html
<input class="form-control" id="MyInspectionModules" type="text" placeholder="Rechercher un module ou sous module">
```

but it's not filtering the values

I need to put the values outside the input text field to be able to filter them but this is not what i need

I tried to put the values in the rows div

```html
<div class="row" id="Mécanosoudure"> bla bla bla
<div class="row" id="boulonnerie"> bla bla bla
<div class="row" id="bâti de fleche"> bla bla bla
```

but this not working too,

Can anyone help with this issue, noting that i need to display the complete row, and not only the column containing the value searched

thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do something like this:
filter all input values and then hide the unwanted results

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#MyInspectionModules").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $("#MyInspection input").filter(function() {
      if(!($(this).val().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) >= 0)){
        $(this).parent().parent().hide();
      }else{
        $(this).parent().parent().show();
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="form-control" id="MyInspectionModules" type="text" placeholder="Rechercher un module ou sous module">

<div id="MyInspection">
  <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
  <input class="form-control form-control-sm" type="text" name="inspectiondetailLibelle_370329" value="Mécanosoudures"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4">
    <input class="form-control form-control-sm" type="text" name="inspectiondetailLibelle_370330" value="Boulonneride"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
  <input class="form-control form-control-sm" type="text" name="inspectiondetailLibelle_370332" value="Bâti de flèche" ></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thx a lot, it's half working,  it's not complettely hiding the unwanted rows

Comment: take a look at the image i uploaded, i have more than one column that i removed fro the code example to make it short

Comment: I can't see how many divs you have... Just try to add `.parent()` to reach your `.row` element

Answer (score 0):

You can show all and hide directly with a selector on value of input :

$("input:not([value*='"+value+"'])").parent().hide();

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#MyInspectionModules").on("keyup", function() {

    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();

    $("#MyInspection input").parent().show();
    $("#MyInspection input:not([value*='"+value+"'])").parent().hide();

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="form-control" id="MyInspectionModules" type="text" placeholder="Rechercher un module ou sous module">

        <div id="MyInspection">
          <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-4">
          <input class="form-control form-control-sm" type="text" name="inspectiondetailLibelle_370329" value="Mécanosoudures"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-4">
            <input class="form-control form-control-sm" type="text" name="inspectiondetailLibelle_370330" value="Boulonneride"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-4">
          <input class="form-control form-control-sm" type="text" name="inspectiondetailLibelle_370332" value="Bâti de flèche" ></div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Shorter code.